# What is the Aggregate/Reduce version of this loop using Java streams?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to come up to speed on the Streams API, but I'm really used to the simplicity of the C# Linq Extension functions and the ability to use the `yield` keyword to create iterators.  Normally I would use:

```
list.Aggregate(set, (acc, a) => { acc.add(a.Id); return acc});
```

Or something like that, but I'm not immediately seeing how this maps to the Streams API.

```
List<SomeObject> objs = ...

Set<String> ids = new HashSet<>();

for (SomeObject a : objs) {
   ids.add(a.getId());
}

assertThat(ids.size(), objs.size());
```

**EDIT:**
Changed SomeObject.getId() to a.getId() in the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following statement should be equivalent to the for-loop in your example.

```
Set<String> ids = objs.stream()
                      .map(a -> a.getId())
                      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

You can also use a *method reference* instead of a *lambda expression*:

```
Set<String> ids = objs.stream()
                      .map(SomeObject::getId)
                      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Ah crap, I just noticed that I had the wrong code.  It shouldn't have been SomeObject.getId(), but a.getId()